# MYSQL : Select * where IN (REPLACE(...))

Tags: mysql

I have the following request :

```
    SELECT value from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id IN
('1','2','10','47')
```

This request give results.

```
value
ok
ok
ok
ok
```

The following request

```
    SELECT value from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id IN
(REPLACE("'1','2','10','47'", 'dont', 'care'))
```

This request doesn't give results because I think its generate `"'1','2','10','47'"` and `entity_id` is an int and not a string.

Thus I tried the following request, but still no results

```
    SELECT value from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id IN
(TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM REPLACE("'1','2','10','47'", 'dont', 'care')))
```

My question is how can I generate a request like the first with a replace ?
Thank you all for your time.

EDIT : DATA SAMPLE :

```
CREATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_varchar (entity_id int(10), value varchar(255));
INSERT INTO catalog_category_entity_varchar VALUES (1,'ok'),(2,'ok'),(10,'ok'),(47,'ok');
```

The initial request I try to achieve to give results

```
    SELECT value from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id
IN ( CONCAT('"', REPLACE('1/2/10/47', '/', '","'), '"') );
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results.

Comment: You haven't said what you are trying to achieve and it's not at all obvious from the non working code.

Comment: @forpas
I simplified the initial request, but the idea is to achieve a WHERE entity_id IN REPLACE(...) while entity_id is an int. But the content of REPLACE(...) is a string, so it doesn't work. Because it's generate ("'1','2','10','47'") instead of ('1','2','10','47').

The initial request is SELECT value from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id IN ( CONCAT('"', REPLACE('1/2/10/47', '/', '","'), '"') );

Comment: So what you have initially is a string like: `'1/2/10/47'`?

Comment: @forpas Yes, as you can see in "EDIT : DATA SAMPLE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the function [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
set @entity = '1/2/10/47';

select * from catalog_category_entity_varchar
where find_in_set(entity_id, replace(@entity, '/', ','))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k9S5JxYVu9L5tGSZ1C2SPa/0).
Results:

```
| entity_id | value |
| --------- | ----- |
| 1         | ok    |
| 2         | ok    |
| 10        | ok    |
| 47        | ok    |
```